# how to clone a div with a same class with nested trigger in each element target

Tags: javascript, html

i need to clone a box div element with children as a trigger, in each box should work the same with the first one, my code not working properly since it's only working for the first element and failed for the second div element (even in the same box), it only working once. here is my code below.

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

for(var i = 0; i < box.length; i++){
  
  var clone = box[i].cloneNode(true);
  var y = box[i].children[0];
  
  y.addEventListener("click", function(){
    container.appendChild(clone);
  }, false)
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <button class="clone">Clone</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cloneNode()` doesn't carry over events bound to the button. Use **[Event Delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)** by adding the eventListener to an ancestor node (`window` and `document` objects are acceptable but I chose `.container` being more practical because of its proximity). When ancestor node detects a button is clicked, we use the [**Event.target**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) and [**Event.currentTarget**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) Event Object properties to determine exactly which button was clicked (`e.target`) and the listener (`e.currentTarget`). For good measure I added another condition that permits only a button to be `e.target`.

So whenever you have multiple `e.target`s like buttons that have an ancestor node in common, add the event listener to the ancestor node instead of adding an event listener to each button.

**Details commented in Demo**

### Demo

```js
// Reference the ancestor node
var con = document.querySelector(".container");

// Register click event on div.con--callback dupeParent()
con.addEventListener('click', dupeParent);

// Pass the Event Object through
function dupeParent(e) {
  /* if the clicked node (e.target) is not the node registered on 
  || click event (e.currentTarget / div.con)...
  || if the clicked node (e.target) is a button...
  || clone the button's parent and add it to div.con
  */
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
      var clone = e.target.parentElement.cloneNode(true);
      this.appendChild(clone);
    }
    // Otherwise quit
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <button class="clone">Clone</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to attach event listener on parent element and then use `event` object to check target property and if its button then you run your code.

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");

container.addEventListener('click', function({target}) {
  if (target.nodeName = 'BUTTON' && target.classList.contains('clone')) {
    const clone = target.parentNode.cloneNode(true);
    container.appendChild(clone)
  }
})
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <button class="clone">Clone</button>
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <button class="clone">Clone</button>
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).on("click", ".clone", function () { 
    $('div.box:first').clone().insertAfter($('div.box:last'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches.

#### Delgation

Delegate event to children of the container.

```js
// Attach event to container and delegate to the children
var $container = $('.container');
$container.on('click', '.clone', function(e) {
  $container.append($(e.target).parent().clone());
});
```

#### Cloning events and data

Copy all data and events for the child.

```js
// Attach event to the child and enable copying of events
var $container = $('.container');
$('.clone').on('click', function(e) {
  $container.append($(e.target).parent().clone(true));
});
```

Comment: There's no indication that jQuery is being used.